# Sign of Overfitting from a Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, overfitting

I have used `RandomForestClassifier` from Sklearn to solve a multiclass classification problem (12 classes in total). I get my `x` and `y` from a pandas dataframe.

```
label_bin = LabelBinarizer()
unique_classes = np.unique(y)
label_bin.fit_transform(unique_classes)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
classifier_RF = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                                       criterion='entropy',
                                       min_samples_split=2,
                                       min_samples_leaf=1,
                                       random_state=1)
y_train_one_hot = label_bin.transform(y_train)
classifier_RF.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot)
y_pred = classifier_RF.predict(x_test)
# Converting predictions to original form
y_pred_orig = label_bin.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Here is a normalized Confusion Matrix obtained from `y_test` and `y_pred_orig`:

[image]

And if make predictions using `x_train`, like this:

```
y_train_pred = classifier_RF.predict(x_train)
y_train_pred = label_bin.inverse_transform(y_train_pred)
```

and get a confusion matrix using `y_train` and `y_train_pred`, this is the result:

[image]

**Question:** By looking at both confusion matrices, can i confirm that my model is overfitting (can't generalize to new unseen data)? If this isn't proof enough, how can i be sure that overfitting is really happening (or not happening)?

As aditional info, this is the `classification_report`:

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support
           0       0.22      0.96      0.35      2863
           1       0.84      0.17      0.29      1918
           2       1.00      0.98      0.99      1987
           3       0.97      0.02      0.04      2020
           4       0.33      0.00      0.00      1928
           5       0.97      0.49      0.65      1995
           6       0.84      0.26      0.39      1951
           7       0.98      0.99      0.99      1997
           8       0.94      0.74      0.83      1987
           9       0.99      0.99      0.99      1967
          10       0.96      0.71      0.81      1985
          11       0.79      0.32      0.46      1916
    accuracy                           0.57     24514
   macro avg       0.82      0.55      0.57     24514
weighted avg       0.80      0.57      0.56     24514
```

**EDIT:** Here is how i got the log loss values (not sure if those are the correct steps):

```
y_train_pred_prob = classifier_RF.predict_proba(x_train)
y_train_pred_probb = np.concatenate([arr[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) for arr in y_train_pred_prob], axis=1)
log_loss_train = log_loss(y_train, y_train_pred_probb)
y_test_pred_prob = classifier_RF.predict_proba(x_test)
y_test_pred_probb = np.concatenate([arr[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1) for arr in y_test_pred_prob], axis=1)
log_loss_test = log_loss(y_test, y_test_pred_probb)
print('Logloss Train:', log_loss_train)
print('Logloss Test:', log_loss_test)

Logloss Train: 0.20318181358124715
Logloss Test: 0.9682325123617269
```

Comment: Can you post the log loss (cross entropy, or Brier score) results based on the training and test set?

Comment: @user2974951 From Sklearn page, i can't really use Brier Score, see: `The Brier score is appropriate for binary and categorical outcomes that can be structured as true or false, but is inappropriate for ordinal variables which can take on three or more values`. Not sure if the log loss is correct, never used it and i don't understand it too well, but check edit for that value.

Comment: Given that you have 24k samples this difference in log loss is huge, so yes the model is overfit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about overfitting is that the model is fitting too closely to the random variation in your training dataset rather than to the underlying trend between your x and your y's. When this happens, the model can show a high performance in predicting the training set because it learned its specific noisy variability, but it could perform poorly in a testing set, because it is more adapted to the noise of the training set than to its signal. Thus, an indicator of overfitting is the difference in performance between training set and testing set. If this difference is large, that could indicate overfitting (although not necessarily, see [this related post](https://medium.com/all-things-ai/in-depth-parameter-tuning-for-random-forest-d67bb7e920d) and the comments).

In your particular case, the confusion matrix for your training set is considerably better than for your testing set, which could indicate overfitting. Also, you practically perfect performance in your training set, which in some applications could be deemed unrealistic and thus indicative of overfitting (unless the problem is actually solvable to 100% accuracy). However, maybe this behavior is common in RandomForest models (see again the related post above).

You also see some weird pattern in the testing confusion matrix where a lot of the confusions are concentrated in column 0. This doesn't necessarily have to be indicative of overfitting, it could just be that under 'uncertain' cases, the model tends to assign class 0. This could happen, for example, if you have many more samples of class 0 than of the other classes (what is called an unbalanced dataset). In that case, for data points where there is high uncertainty, the model may rely more on its prior, and assign the class with the highest a priori probability, leading to a pattern like the one seen there.

Finally, you mention the model's incapability of generalizing to new data. Your model does show some decent performance in the testing set. As I mentioned above, the observed pattern of having a lot of confusions in the first column doesn't necessarily reflect overfitting. As also mentioned above, your model does show some indication of overfitting, and it would be desirable to try to see if overfitting is actually making your testing performance worse. You could try to reduce overfitting by increasing the parameters min_samples_split and min_samples_leaf (see [this blogpost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361983/random-forest-fully-fits-training-sample)). If this modification leads to improved testing performance, then you indeed have overfitting hindering your model's predictive capability. Whether your model is useful or not, I think you should base on the confusion matrix of the test set, and whether the results there suit your purposes.

Comment: Thank you, this was really informative. Check the `support` column in the `classification_report`. That shows how many samples for each class i have in my dataset. Each class (from class 1 to 11) has around 70% the number of samples of class 0. Can i say that this is a unbalanced dataset?

Comment: Note that I edited my answer. Yes, it is unbalanced, which just means that some classes have more samples than others. That could explain why you see the result with confusions concentrated on column 0. However, that a dataset is unbalanced doesn't mean much on its own (most real world datasets are unbalanced to some degree). The problem can be that some samples are very difficult to classify, and the model then just classifies them as the most likely class. If samples were easier to classify, the unbalanced property could have a small effect. Consider upvoting the answer if it was useful