# My random forrest regressor was overfitting so I tried to use randomsearchcv but I still got a worse result, what should I change?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, scikit-learn

I tried to fix my overfitting with randomized search cross-validation. These are my params:

I set 100 estimators but that is irrelevant for the overfitting. I read log2 was best for regressors somewhere. I am not sure about max depth being correct I found that number somewhere on stack exchange saying it was good. I set 5,8 and 3,6 because in min_samples_split and min_samples_leaf as I saw online that the larger they were the closest they would be to overfitting but ofcourse the lower they are the more they will underfit so is this what I should change?

In terms of performance, this one is worse compared to the time I did not use cross-validation. When I used random forest regressor (n=100) with default settings it also behaved badly (has a negative r^2 score) with the validation data but at least with the training data, it has an r^2 score of 60. I know I shouldn't test it with training data but I used it as proof of overfitting. This code I have below neither performs well(has a negative r^2 score) on the validation data nor on the training data, i.e this is proof for me it is under-fitted. What should I do to fix this?

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.utils import shuffle



#[32..features]:
x=(1474277, 34)
y=(1474277, 1)

X, Y = shuffle(x, y, random_state=0)


print("x=",np.shape(X),"   y;",np.shape(Y))


# Number of trees in random forest
n_estimators = [100]
# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['log2']
# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [5,6,7,8]
# Minimum number of samples required to split a node
min_samples_split = [5, 8]
# Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
min_samples_leaf = [3, 6]
# Method of selecting samples for training each tree
bootstrap = [True]
# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
print(random_grid)

rf = RandomForestRegressor()

Reg = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions = random_grid, n_iter = 16,n_jobs=-1, random_state=42)


print("done")

print(Reg.best_params_)
```

output of Reg.best_params:

```
{'n_estimators': 100, 'min_samples_split': 8, 'min_samples_leaf': 3, 'max_features': 'log2', 'max_depth': 8, 'bootstrap': True}
```

Comment: This duplicate has a number of helpful suggestions. TL;DR set `n_estimators` and `max_depth` much larger and tune `max_features` because it's the most important hyperparameter. The things you're tuning have comparatively modest effects on model quality.

Comment: @Sycorax I have looked at them and have removed the unimportant ones and now here are my parameters. Is max depth large enough and have I tuned max_features correctly?

n_estimators = [110,120,130]
# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['sqrt','auto']
# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [14,15,16,17,18]
# Minimum number of samples required to split a node

Comment: The procedure you've suggested -- tuning some and then tuning some others -- is unlikely to succeed. Moreover, with such a small number of `n_estimators`, your results will be strongly influenced by randomness. Here's a demonstration: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348245/do-we-have-to-tune-the-number-of-trees-in-a-random-forest Follow the suggestions in the duplicate.

Comment: I will not tune n_estimators and will have it set on 1000. I have changed max_depth to max_depth = [25,30,50].  Just as the first comment said (this is high for me).  

Can you explain what you meant by " tuning some and then tuning some others -- is unlikely to succeed." Sorry for being naggy.