# Determining the number of trees in a random forest model a priori fitting

Tags: random-forest, hyperparameter, law-of-large-numbers

The [answer to "Do we have to tune the number of trees in a random forest?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/348246/228809) suggests using as large a number of trees in a forest as possible. Is there a rule-of-thumb for choosing this "large enough number of trees" a priori? Perhaps as a function of the number of observations and number of explanatory variables?

Comment: Very much a non-answer:
I personally use $500$ and/or what I can compute  within a time-frame I find reasonable (~1'). If the performance has not converged until that point, then random forests is evidently not the right tool for the job. If it has converged, then great.

Comment: @usεr11852 have you any insight or intuition on the relationship between your method's success and size of your data set?

Comment: Yes. My intuition is that I am estimating a conditional mean using a particular estimator (a CART here). If after 500 samples that conditional mean is not stable enough, then this methodology is unsuitable. Remember that ultimately RFs are supposed to help with *the variance* not the bias of the CART estimates, i.e. the bias won't get better if we add more trees so if after 500 samples the variance is still strong, then I will have doubts on whether the bias is even OK at which point I might as well try some other method.

Comment: thanks for sharing your experience and insights!