# Can the randomness in random forests lead to some samples/features being used more/less than others, resulting in skewed and biased results?

Tags: python, random-forest

The way I see it, is that since samples and features are chosen randomly, there is a chance, small as it may seem, that at the end of it all, some samples and some features *might* end up not being used *at all*, and some might be used a lot more than others, on average, which can lead to skewed and biased final results.

Does that make sense? If yes, then is there a way to make sure that at the end, throughout the whole forest, all samples and all features would end up being used in trees on average the same amount of times, ensuring that no sample/feature would be left out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not make a lot of sense because if we have enough trees what is described *won't* happen. The way to ensure this is to monitor how the overall random forest (RF) performance changes as more trees are added (see the  CV.SE thread on: *[Do we have to tune the number of trees in a random forest?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348245/do-we-have-to-tune-the-number-of-trees-in-a-random-forest/348246#348246)* for an in-depth discussion on that, Sycorax's answer is gold). Notice that RFs primarily reduce variance, not bias,  ie. any single base learner is "as biased as" the overall ensemble, just the ensemble's prediction is more stable via [*bagging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating).

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the shout-out. To my thinking, the key is that RF results hinge on identical distributions and independence. If you're sampling so that all observations or features are selected the same number of times, you're implicitly giving up those properties, which implies you're venturing into uncertain territory & perhaps the proofs for RF results don't apply.